# 動詞の前の「と」の使い方と意味

Tags: particles

どうしてこの下の文章で「と」を使われましたか。

> 一、二年**と**うけもたれた先生。

この「と」の使い方と意味を説明していただけませんか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

考え方は２つあります。（本当は１つしかない）

ひとつは、[この辞書のページ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8/)の、２ （文や句をそのまま受けて）動作・作用・状態の内容を表す。引用の「と」という説明にあるとおり、引用の助詞とする解釈。

または、「５ （副詞に付いて新たな副詞をつくり）ある状態を説明する意を表す」ものとみなすこともできます。一、二年などの数詞は副詞なので。ただ、この場合のように「と」のあるなしで全く意味が変わってしまうものまで含めるのは反則的な解釈な気がしますが。

引用の「と」は、「発話や思考を表す動詞と共に用いられその内容を表す」と説明されることが多いですが、実際はあらゆる動詞と一緒に使われてその内容を表します。

いずれにせよ例題では、クラスを受け持ったとして、ではどんな様態で受け持ったのか、その内容を「一、二年」と表しています。普通に解釈すれば、一年と二年を引き続いて、ということになります。

以下のように比喩に使われることもあります。

- 山と積もった（まるで山のように積もった）
- 煙が雲とたなびく（まるで雲のように棚引く）※「雲と一緒に」ではない

もはや引用ではないじゃないかと思えますが、学者が仕事するのを待つのみです。